# how to write a value into sales orderlines using button

Tags: odoo-8

i would like to add values to a field(ship) in sales orderlines using a button when i tring below mentioned code i got error ***Expected singleton: sale.order.line(41, 42)***

```
def writes(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    sale_order_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    sale_order_line_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order.line')
    sale_obj=sale_order_obj.order_line
    for line in sale_obj:
        sale_order_line_obj.write(cr, uid, line.id, {'ship': sale_obj.ship.id}, context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood i think you need edit your loop

```
for line in sale_obj:
    for line_obj in sale_order_line_obj:
        line_obj.write(cr, uid, line.id, {'ship': sale_obj.ship.id}, context=context)
```